# Will Snowflake ODBC connection stay valid even if the OAuth access token expires?

Tags: oauth, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my code I use Snowflake with OAuth and ODBC. The access token is appended to the connection string and that is used in ODBC API function SQLDriverConnect. I have experimented with it and it seems that the connection is valid (usable) even after the access token expires. Can I rely on this? Is it the case that once I have the connection, I can use it as long as I want?

If I cannot rely on this, I think I would have to check every usage of ODBC API and in case of an error I would have to refresh the token, somehow make the existing connection use the new access token and try again. But that seems difficult. If the connection is valid even after the access token used to get the connection expires, all I need to check is SQLDriverConnect and refresh the token if SQLDriverConnect fails.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens have a short life; typically 10 minutes. When the access token expires, the client can send a refresh token to obtain new access tokens.

Since access token are very short lived, we use refresh token so that with the help of refresh token, another access token can be sent without asking the user to go through entire authorization flow.

When the access token expires, client sends Snowflake another request with the refresh token and Snowflake does the checks and sends back another access token. This does not affect user flow and it is happening in the background without affecting what the user is doing.

If the integration is configured to prevent sending refresh tokens, the user must repeat the above steps to re-authorize the client.

The refresh token validity is set when the [security integration](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-security-integration.html) is created:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] SECURITY INTEGRATION [IF NOT EXISTS]
  <name>
  TYPE = OAUTH
  OAUTH_CLIENT = <partner_application>
  [ ENABLED = { TRUE | FALSE } ]
  [ OAUTH_ISSUE_REFRESH_TOKENS = TRUE | FALSE ]
  [ OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY = <integer> ]
  [ OAUTH_USE_SECONDARY_ROLES = IMPLICIT | NONE ]
  [ BLOCKED_ROLES_LIST = ( '<role_name>' [ , '<role_name>' , ... ] ) ]
  [ COMMENT = '<string_literal>' ]
```

For more information see [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-intro.html)

Comment: I have updated my question. It is not about how to refresh the token, but when the refresh is needed. What can fail if access token expires. CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE is interesting. I don't think we set it, so probably the default is used, but it should not be a problem - 4 hours should be more than enough for my sessions.

Comment: @VojtěchFried I have updated my answer, does it makes more sense now?

Comment: It makes sense, but it does not answer the question. My refresh token is valid and I know how to use it. The problem is what happens with the connection when access token expires. If the connection will work normally, I only have to refresh the token before creating another connection.

Comment: I thought this answered your concern: "When the access token expires, client sends Snowflake another request with the refresh token and Snowflake does the checks and sends back another access token. This does not affect user flow and it is happening in the background without affecting what the user is doing."

Answer (score 0):

I have used Snowflake OAuth and used JDBC. For JDBC as well the Connection Object still lives even if the Access Token is expired.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).